# Pass a variable from one frame to another

Tags: java, string

I have a string in one frame named uname

```
String uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
String password = new String(pword);
```

and in my another one (shown below) frame want the String uname...Change uname static and add following code

```
public SectionsFclty(String uname) {
    initComponents();
    jLabelUsername.setText(uname);
}
```

But in my first frame

```
 new SectionsFclty().setVisible(true);//   shows an error
```

and also I want to create exe file from .jar.I know its easy but i want the installation screen including privacy policy and also accept agreement check box etc like our normal application installation platform.My application needs the MySQL database at the back end.So i want that installation also in my applications installation time if the user really wants that.Please help me.

Comment: The best way would be to pass it as an argument to method `SectionsFclty(String uname)` , terrible way would be to make the `uname` `static`.

Comment: You should call the constructor the way specified in the answer. That is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Pass it as an argument and use it when you instantiate the SectionsFclty class. So your constructor of SectionsFclty would look like this-

```
public SectionsFclty(String uname) {

    initComponents();
    jLabelUsername.setText(uname);

}
```

You would instantiate it like this-

```
SectionsFclty sf = new SectionsFclty(uname);
```

Comment: new SectionsFclty().setVisible(true);//shows an error in first frame

Comment: @SaranyaSaru Please edit your question to show the changes you have made to your code and the *exact* error message that you need help with.

Comment: @SaranyaSaru Maybe you are not initializing properly. SectionsFclty f = new SectionsFclty(ParentFrame.this);
                f.setVisible(true);